# Passing data between PHP and Wordpress and vice versa

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help or advise. I have a wordpress website and on it "CSS3 Responsive Wordpress 3 column pricing table" plugin.
Problem is I have a login/Sign up dual purpose form done in PHP, I want that when user clicks on Login or Sign up at 
the top of the menu, the PHP form is loaded and the user can login if he is alrady a user or fill up his name, email 
and password and when he cllicks on the Register button he will be taken to the membership pricing table where he 
compares the plans and when he clicks the "Sign up" button of the plan of his choice, the selected plan, user name, 
email etc will be passed to the registration process which proceeds with a mail sent to the user who validates the 
registration by clicking on the link in the mail, clicking the link will load a form to login and if the login is 
successful the user gains access to a PHP dashboard with the details user filled or selected like name, email,
membership are reflected on the dashboard.
The problem is that the programmer I have hired for the job says it is not possible to transfer data from PHP to WP 
and vice versa but something tells me it is possible.
I would like to know whether it is possible and if it is, any hints on how to achieve what I have explained.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to import the functionality inside Wordpress or if you want to use an external PHP script using an iFrame.

The developer is correct and if you want to use native WP signup functionality, you will have to convert the PHP code into a plugin.

The alternative to this would be adding the PHP code as an iFrame on your WP website but this may not give your visitors the best customer experience.

I would recommend converting your PHP Script into WP Plugin or switching to a basic PHP/MySQL website.

Comment: Hello Veggito, thanks for the explanation, I must confess that your explanation is beyond my scope. I am not for any particular alternative all I want is for the registration process to pass through the pricing table so that the user can compare and select a plan and then the registration can proceed in PHP.  Thinking in layman's term how about creating a work DB, when the user inputs the info in the PHP form it is stored in the DB and control swifts to the pricing table and the user selection is stored in the DB and then control is passed back to PHP and the registration proceeds.

Comment: Can you give me a link to your website? I can take a better look at it and suggest some easy alternative. Alternatively, please provide me with your skype id and we can have a chat about this.

Comment: Hello Veggito
Thanks so much,speechless.
http://myjapanaddress.com/
Pricetable:http://myjapanaddress.com/membership-plans-2/
Mainmenu => click signin => PHP Form
http://myjapanaddress.com/mydashboard/
User fills & clicks Register=> Membership-plans-2 => choose plan=>
clicks "Signup" (*present signup form that is loaded not needed)=>registration back to PHP form
ofcourse PHP form isn't loaded again
Selected plan reflected in dashboard setting
*Note "Select Plan" & pulldown of PHP form not needed
"Click to view all Membership Plan" an eyesore, also not needed
skype: nibara@live.jp

Comment: Hello, My problem is still unsolved, Is there anyone out there who can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: marvelsolns I added you on skype but there was no response from you! Can you please check my request and add me?

Comment: Veggito, Thanks for the response. I have checked and there is no record of any request from you. Could please check whether you rightly stated my ID.